# React.JS + axios parsing error in initialState. Axios is installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

    const [people, setPeople] = useState( initialState:[])

    useEffect(effect: () => {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test-api/"
        }).then(response => {
            setPeople(response.data)
        })
    }, deps: [])

  return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1> Завидуй </h1>
          <ul>
              {people.map(p => (
                  <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>
              ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After npm run build

```
Line 6:55:  Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis

  4 | function App() {
  5 |
> 6 |     const [people, setPeople] = useState( initialState:[])
    |                                                       ^
  7 |
  8 |     useEffect(effect: () => {
  9 |         axios({
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! mainapp-ui@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the mainapp-ui@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-04T12_13_05_315Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a syntax error. No need to specify parameter names when passing arguments into a function.

Try this

```js
const [people, setPeople] = useState([])
```

Let me guess, you're WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA user?

Comment: THX bro (pycharm user :/)